# Oracle SQL - How To Loop Through Records Using Pagination?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using an Oracle database where I have a table containing 20 records

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    MY_RECORD_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
    SOME_DATA_1 VARCHAR2(200), 
    SOME_DATA_2 VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (4, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (5, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (6, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (7, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (8, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (9, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (10, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (11, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (12, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (13, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (14, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (15, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (16, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (17, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (18, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (19, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (20, 'BLAH1', 'BLAH2');
```

What I'd like to do is to iterate through this table selecting 5 records at a time based on the `MY_RECORD_ID` column.  The `OFFSET` and `FETCH` commands would appear to allow me to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY MY_RECORD_ID 
OFFSET 0 ROWS -- start at the first row
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

I'd like to insert the above statement into a loop so that I can perform operations on the data for each of the five rows (so this would execute 4 times in total).  Is there a way to do this using a stored procedure?

Comment: If you describe your intend, we can give you accurate answer. Why do you need to do something like this?

Comment: Why you want to loop for every fetch ? Why dont you loop for every row ? Honestly I am not sure if you can add the select value in an array.

Comment: I want to perform an MD5 Hash on the records in MyTable in groups of 5 per time.  So I need to be able to iterate through the table by getting the first 5 records, hashing them and storing the resulting hash, getting the next 5 records, hashing them and storing the resulting hash, etc.

Comment: Pagination is a tricky issue and performance will tend to suck. It won't matter for a toy set of twenty records but then this seems a forced example anyway. Anyway [this excerpt from *Use The Index Luke* is required reading on the topic](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Analytic Functions for this kind of requests

```
SELECT my_record_id, some_data_1, some_data_2
  FROM (
        SELECT CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mt.my_record_id) / 5/*set the page size*/) page_id
             ,mt.* 
          FROM MyTable mt
       ) t
 WHERE page_id = 1 /* set the desired page*/
ORDER BY my_record_id
```

You can check this documentation

**Analytics Functions**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

**Ask Tom**

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1137577300346084930

**Other Example**

https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-top-n-and-pagination-queries

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via using the bulk collect.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_MyTable_tab IS TABLE OF MyTable%ROWTYPE;
  l_tab    t_MyTable_tab ; 
  CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   MyTable;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT 5; --- Here 5 is your limiting number

    -- Process contents of collection here.
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_tab.count || ‘ rows’);
    EXIT WHEN c_data%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP
  CLOSE c_data;
END;
/
```